# Trying to install cyanogenmod on nexus 7 but can't get into Team Win Recovery Project

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-7

I have followed the steps from [How to Install CyanogenMod on the Google Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi, 2012 version) ("grouper")](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_grouper)

> 4. If you are not already in recovery, boot to recovery mode now.
>      Hold Volume Up, Volume Down, & the Power button. Continue to hold all three until the screen flashes, then release all buttons.
> 5. In Team Win Recovery Project, select menu choices by tapping on the appropriately labelled button.

After #4, you are suddenly supposed to be in team win recovery project. But I'm not. I am in the menu that gives you the options "start, restart bootloader, recovery mode, and power off".  If I choose recovery mode, I see a picture of an android and his chest/belly is open with a red triangle.

How do I get into team win recovery project?

Alternatives are also welcome. Hand holding will be needed though... I'm a noob to mods.

Comment: You can use command `adb reboot recovery `.

Comment: Since your recovery is broken. You should use the other part of the tutorial. `Installing a custom recovery using fastboot`

Comment: A nexus? If I remember right, spam buttons. It sometimes works

Comment: Spam buttons? I don't follow

Comment: When I type adb reboot recovery, I see an image of an android with his chest open and a red triangle with an exclamation point @VivekJi

Comment: I went through the tutorial from top to bottom @RahulParashar. So I completed that section before moving onto "Installing CyanogenMod from recovery"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do it through command line from your PC.

Install adb drivers in PC [15 seconds ADB installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118#post48915118)

Download the TWRP img file for Nexus 7 from twrp website [TWRP for Nexus 7](https://dl.twrp.me/grouper/)

Rename the downloaded img file to "recovery.img" and move this to the ADB folder that was downloaded earlier. Make sure you have ADB.exe, fastboot.exe and the recovery.img in the same directory

Enable developer options and USB Debugging in your device

Connect the device to PC. Make sure device is detected if not download the USB drivers.

Once devices is detected, open a command prompt and change location to the ADB directory. Issue the command "adb devices". This should give your device ID as the output.

Executive the following commands carefully:

1. "adb reboot bootloader" - the device will reboot in fastboot mode
2. Once device shows up fast boot screen, type " fastboot devices " and make sure device ID is listed
3. Type "fastboot flash recovery recovery.img" . this installs the TWRP image into the device. If successful you will see an Okay message in command prompt.
4. Issue command "fastboot reboot" and wait for device to reboot normally. Once this is done you can try the key combination to boot into recovery.  If everything went well you should be greeted with the TWRP recovery instead of the stock Android recovery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Followed your instructions and got it working. Seems like the trick was to rename the image file from whatever it downloaded as to recovery.img? That did the trick!

Comment: great to know that!